# Different Java objects having the same address, IsSameObject not working, and related global ref management problems

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've been banging my head on this problem for a week, and now I'm starting to understand what's going on, but no idea why, or how to fix it.

Let me describe what I'm doing. I have an assortment of various objects in Java, and I have a native library. Java objects inform the library of their existence by calling `NativeLibrary.AddObject(this)`. The native library has a container of `jobject`s where I store global references to the Java objects, obtained with `env->NewGlobalRef(object)`. The native library uses these stored references to access the Java objects, and it does work fine.

And here's the crucial part that does NOT work. Obviously, I want to be able to delete Java objects, not only add them. So, when a Java object is no longer needed, it calls `NativeLibrary.RemoveObject(this)`. The native library implements it by iterating the list of stored objects (which are all global references, as you may remember) and finding a match with `env->IsSameObject(passedObject, storedObjectGlobalReference)`.
And here's where the problem is: it doesn't work as expected, the Java objects are not matched to their global references properly. When I started digging and logging all the calls with all the parameters, I noticed a weird thing: the `jobject` parameter of the native call (which is `this` of Java objects) has the same value for different objects! Moreover, this value changes between the ``NativeLibrary.AddObject(this)`and`NativeLibrary.RemoveObject(this)` calls for the same object!

So, what's going on, and how can I store, keep track of and delete the references to Java objects in native code? To reiterate: everything works fine as long as I only create and store global refs; the correct objects receive notifications via these refs, no problem. But as soon as I try deleting these references via `env->DeleteGlobalRef`, I find out that in the `NativeLibrary.RemoveObject(this)` implementation fails to match the stored reference to the passed `jobject`.

Comment: If i understand it, you are referring to 'this' as a local reference to object, that is removed right after finishing execution of method. Therefor you cannot compare integer values of pointers to those 'this' objects.

Comment: Can you post native parts of `NativeLibrary.AddObject(this)` and `NativeLibrary.RemoveObject(this)`?

Comment: @V-master: that would explain a few things. So you're saying that comparing the `jobject` value (which is `this` in Java code) between native calls is pointless? But that doesn't explain why `IsSameObject` provides wrong results and wrong references get matched...

Comment: @Andrew0x1: it's more complicated than I described, involves several C++ classes and different methods. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong from your description... given a jobject, find a global reference that IsSameObject, and DeleteGlobalRef. So long as AddObject guarantees that you only have one global reference to that jobject, it should be 1:1. Can you be more specific about how "Java objects are not matched to their global references properly", and why you think that's a failing in the VM? Perhaps give an example of a pattern of calls that fails.

Comment: @fadden: actually, I may call `AddObject` several times for the same object, and then call `RemoveObject` the same number of times. Right now I'm refactoring the whole system to make it much simpler so that I can post the code. Will expand the question tomorrow.

Comment: If you want to debug if the objects are actually the same, try to compare jobject hashCode() or  System.identityHashCode(), there should be same for equal objects

Comment: @V-master: I did actually use `hashCode` some time ago, but then was discouraged from doing so since it's been explained to me that `hashCode` can realistically produce collisions. Never heard of `System.identityHashCode()`, though, will research it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using iterators to find the matching jobject? I consider myself a fairly competent programmer, but when removing while iterating I always get it wrong what the iterator points to.

Comment: @user2543253: No, that's not it. But I get what you're saying, erasing elements from a container while iterating over it is a pain if you do it manually. That's why you have to use the erase-remove idiom which makes it very simple: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem. The root cause was that the added item `NativeLibrary.AddObject(this)` not was the same object when I called `NativeLibrary.RemoveObject(this)`. I was using junit and this was causing the problem, because junit create multiples objects to run each test. I found the problem using `System.out.println` with the `object` in Java side. Before add function `System.out.println("add object: " + sameObject);` and before remove function `System.out.println("remove object: " + sameObject);`. Sorry for poor english, I hope this help someone.